# How is it possible to create a spinner with images instead of text?

Tags: android, spinner

Given the code bellow, is it possible to have images instead of text in the array planets?

```
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);    
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(            
            this, R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);    
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and

```
    <string name="planet_prompt">Choose a planet</string>
    <string-array name="planets">        
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>        
        <item>Mars</item>        
        <item>Jupiter</item>        
        <item>Saturn</item>        
        <item>Uranus</item>        
        <item>Neptune</item>    
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it is look at the code below:

---

```
array of data

// stores the image database icons
    private static Integer[] imageIconDatabase = { R.drawable.ball,
            R.drawable.catmouse, R.drawable.cube, R.drawable.fresh,
            R.drawable.guitar, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.teapot };

    // stores the image database names
    private String[] imageNameDatabase = { "ball", "catmouse", "cube", "fresh",
            "guitar", "orange", "teapot" };
```

---

creating List of hashmaps

```
private void initializeImageList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < imageNameDatabase.length; i++) {
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            map.put("Name", imageNameDatabase[i]);
            map.put("Icon", imageIconDatabase[i]);
            spinnerList.add(map);
        }
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource((spinnerList.get(0).get("Icon"));
        spinnerList.get(0).get("Name");
    }
```

---

assigning spinner to adapter

```
public void createAddDialog() {
        // TODO
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_editoradd_dialog);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAddImageList);
        CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this,
                spinnerData, R.layout.spinner_view, new String[] { "Name",
                        "Icon" }, new int[] { R.id.imageNameSpinner,
                        R.id.imageIconSpinner });
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

---

the adapter used above is as given below..

```
package com.tcs.CustomListViewGeneration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> dataRecieved;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        dataRecieved =data;
        mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_view,
                    null);
        }
    //  HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageNameSpinner))
                .setText((String) dataRecieved.get(position).get("Name"));
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageIconSpinner))
                .setBackgroundResource(dataRecieved.get(position).get("Icon")));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: There is no explanation required I guess as such , the custome adapter structure is just the basic one which we always follows.Also the code is not complex and is divided into functions and classes so that there is no need for you to be einstien to understand it!

Comment: What is spinner list

Answer (score 25):

I just needed a super easy solution for a fixed set of images in a spinner, so I did this:

```
   public class SimpleImageArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private Integer[] images;

    public SimpleImageArrayAdapter(Context context, Integer[] images) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, images);
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getImageForPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getImageForPosition(position);
    }

    private View getImageForPosition(int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[position]);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            return imageView;
    }
   }
```

And then in the code you can just use it like this:

```
    SimpleImageArrayAdapter adapter = new SimpleImageArrayAdapter(context, 
        new Integer[]{R.drawable.smiley1, R.drawable.smiley2, R.drawable.smiley3, R.drawable.smiley4, R.drawable.smiley5});
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was struggling to get images into the dropdownview, as the [official documentation for arrayadapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) doesn't seem to mention `getDropDownView(...)`, only `getView(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still using Spinners in 2020, but here's a Kotlin version of this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22216375/6007104):

```
class MySpinnerAdapter(context: Context, images: Array<Int>) :
    ArrayAdapter<Int>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, images) {

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup) =
        getImageForPosition(position)

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup) =
        getImageForPosition(position)

    private fun getImageForPosition(position: Int) = ImageView(context).apply {
        setBackgroundResource(getItem(position)!!)
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution using SimpleImageArrayAdapter works perfectly except when the Android version is Marshmallow or older in which case you have to use an ArrayAdapter with a string-array like that specified in the original question otherwise your dropdown list will be an empty white box.