# images in Spinner lists

Tags: java, android, android-xml

In the response to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114475, no corresponding XML was provided.  Could I get the XML files that demonstrate the capability to insert images in Spinners.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this

spinner_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/imageNameSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/xR.id.imageIconSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

list_editoradd_dialog.xml   //This would be the bare minimum

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerAddImageList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How about the XML for R.layout.list_editoradd_dialog and R.layout.spinner_view?   Thanks.

Comment: What I gave originally was the spinner_view.  I should have labeled it.  Just added the list_editoradd_dialog.xml

Comment: Could you make this example actually execute displaying the Spinner? I am still having problems both syntactically and during execution (when I alter the syntax to allow execution). For example, I had to add the Integer cast to the statement: ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageIconSpinner)).setBackgroundResource((Integer) dataRecieved.get(position).get("Icon"));                                                           Thanks for your help.  Mike

Comment: I think that code is a full example.  What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the following error at the spinnerList.add(map); statement:  The method add(capture#3-of ? extends Map<String,?>) in the type List<capture#3-of ? extends Map<String,?>> is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap)