# How to add Image to spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to add an image to spinner I have tried like:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/myImage" />
```

But with this code the sign of down arrow on spinner becomes invisible please tell me how to solve that problem!! I want to do exactly Like in this image

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the background of spinner ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609231/how-is-it-possible-to-create-a-spinner-with-images-instead-of-text

Answer (score 16):

Create a **row.xml** in `/res/layout/`. To to setup the layout on each row.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/weekofday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in Java file add this code as

```
 Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, YourArrayHere);
  mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Dude, where is (R.id.spinner defined ?

Comment: Where do you set the image view?

Comment: you didn't even mention the image view in java.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I have just used standard layout for spinner items and override just a little the ArrayAdapter.

```
private class PaymentTypeArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PaymentType> {

    public PaymentTypeArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        addAll(PaymentType.getPaymentTypes());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        PaymentType paymentType = getItem(position);
        label.setText(paymentType.getStringResourceId());
        label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, paymentType.
                getImageResourceId(), 0);

        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView label = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

        PaymentType paymentType = getItem(position);
        label.setText(paymentType.getStringResourceId());
        label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, paymentType.
                getImageResourceId(), 0);

        return label;
    }
}
```

Then set up adapter for your spinner:

```
mPaymentTypeArrayAdapter = new PaymentTypeArrayAdapter(getContext());
    setAdapter(mPaymentTypeArrayAdapter);
```

In this approach the key was to use the [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for the label