# How can I set a spinner prompt as an image

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, prompt

I have a spinner with a prompt. Is it possible to have the prompt as an image? Do I need a `CustomArrayAdapter`?

This is currently my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
  Spinner legalSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.legal);

     legal = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,android.R.id.text1);
    legalSpinner.setPrompt("Places");
    legal.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    legalSpinner.setAdapter(legal);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I would like the prompt on my spinner to be an image from my drawable directory. @XaverKapeller

Comment: Does this solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151847/how-to-add-image-to-spinner-in-android ?

Comment: I would like to change the prompt to a image, not all the rows in the spinner. @XaverKapeller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to fix the problem on my own after a few days of work. If you want to set a spinner prompt as a image you must use a `ImageGetter`.

```
legalSpinner.setPrompt(Html.fromHtml("<img src=\"image\"", new Html.ImageGetter() {
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String s) {
            Drawable drawFromPath;
            int path =
                    MyClass.this.getResources().getIdentifier(s, "drawable",
                            getBaseContext().getPackageName());
            drawFromPath = (Drawable) MyClass.this.getResources().getDrawable(path);
            drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0, drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return drawFromPath;
        }
    }
```